# Valid currency formats by locale

Tags: formatting, locale, currency, intl

Does anyone know where I can get a list of valid currency formats by locale code? I've extracted formats from Intl (js object) and compared to those, which we can see in Windows Regional Settings and saw that they are different. For example, for "be-BY" we have "$ 123,123.35" in Intl, but on Windows it is "123 123,35 $".

So what is correct? And is there a complete and correct list of this anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery library https://github.com/jquery/globalize is an answer. Formatting of numbers, dates, currencies by locale.